# Best way to group list of doubles, to add up to a specific value

Tags: c#

I have task, that I'm unsure on how i should approach.

there's a list of doubles, and i need to group them together to add up to a specific value.

Say i have:
14.6666666666666,
14.6666666666666,
2.37499999999999,
1.04166666666665,
1.20833333333334,
1.20833333333334,
13.9583333333333,
1.20833333333334,
3.41666666666714,
3.41666666666714,
1.20833333333334,
1.20833333333334,
14.5416666666666,
1.20833333333335,
1.04166666666666,

And i would like to group into set values such as 12,14,16

I would like to take the highest value in the list then group it with short ones to equal the closest value above.

example:
take double 14.6666666666666, and group it with 1.20833333333334 to bring me close to 16, and if there are anymore small doubles left in the list, group them with that as well.

Then move on to the next double in the list..

Comment: Do you have a tolerance for how close you want to get to the desired sums?

Comment: So adding up the highest to lowest, 2nd highest to 2nd lowest, and so on...?

Comment: No Tolerance to how close,

Comment: Basically i'm create a material optimizer, were the list of doubles are lengths of material, and i'm just trying to group the material cuts longer with shorter to get the most efficient use of material.

Comment: What if the combination that brings you closest to the desired sum doesn't include the largest available size, but can be assembled from a bunch of shorter ones? Or if it's made up of the 1st, 2nd, and 4th largest numbers, skipping the third?

Comment: I was going to save that for the end... if there was no large numbers available.
it can be made of of large ones as well, if it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's literally the "Cutting stock Problem" (Sometimes called the 1 Dimensional Bin Packing Problem).  There are a number of well documented solutions.

- The only way to get the "Optimal" solution (other than a quantum computer) is to cycle through every combination, and select the best outcome.
- A quicker way to get an "OK" solution is called the "First Fit Algorithm".  It takes the requested values in the order they come, and removes them from the first piece of material that can fulfill the request.
- The "First Fit Algorithm" can be slightly improved by pre-ordering the the values from largest to smallest, and pre-ordering the materials from smallest to largest.  You could also uses the material that is closest to being completely consumed by the request, instead of the first piece that can fulfill the request.
- A compromise, but one that requires more code is a "Genetic Algorithm".  This is an over simplification, but you could use the basic idea of the "First Fit Algorithm", but randomly swap two of the values before each pass.  If the efficiency increases, you keep the change, and if it decreases, you go back to the last state.  Repeat until a fixed amount of time has passed or until you're happy.

Comment: Thanks!
Im a hobbyist programmer, so didn't know how to explain or what to search for. This opens quite a few doors.

Answer (score 0):

Put the doubles in a list and sort them. Grab the highest value that is less than the target to start. Then loop through from the start of the list adding the values until you reach a point where adding the value will put you over the limit.

```
var threshold = 16;
List<double> values = new List<double>();
values.Add(14.932034);
etc...
```

Sort the list:

```
values = values.OrderBy(p => p).ToList();
```

Grab the highest value that is less than your threshold:

```
// Highest value under threshold
var highestValue = values.Where(x => x < threshold).Max();
```

Now perform your search and calculations until you reach your solution:

```
currentValue = highestValue
Console.WriteLine("Starting with: " + currentValue);
foreach(var val in values)
{
    if(currentValue + val <= theshold)
    {
        currentValue = currentValue + val;
        Console.WriteLine(" + " + val.ToString());
    }
    else
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine("Finished with: " + currentValue.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Repeat the process for the next value and so on until you've output all of the solutions you want.